# Oracle JSON functions not adding leading zeros to decimals

Tags: json, sql-server, oracle

Using [`json_array`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/JSON_ARRAY.html#GUID-46C) in Oracle 12c:

```
SELECT
  COLUMN_VALUE "value"
, json_array(COLUMN_VALUE) "json_output"
FROM TABLE(SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(5.00, -5.00, 0.50, -0.50, 0.05, -0.05))

value   json_output
5       [5]
-5      [-5]
0.5     [0.5]    <--Zero before decimal
-0.5    [-0.5]
.05     [.05]    <--No zero before decimal
-.05    [-.05]
```

The last two `json_output` strings, `[.05]` and `[-.05]`, do not conform to [RFC 4627](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) and fail validation at [JSONlint](https://jsonlint.com/) and [Code Beautify](https://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator).

Parsing them on SQL Server 2017 fails:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON('[.05]')

Msg 13609, Level 16, State 4, Line 137
JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '.' is found at position 1.
```

How can I force Oracle to produce RFC4627 compliant JSON?  Alternatively, how can I get SQL Server to parse the noncompliant format?

EDIT: This is a large (for my resources) datastream, about 1TB/hour. I'm hoping for a cleaner solution than editing the JSON strings mid-flight.

Comment: Are you very much attached to the values being numbers? Otherwise you could just output formatted strings and parse those back. Not ideal, obviously, but given that JSON is text anyway...

Comment: It's worth noting that the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/JSON_ARRAY.html) implies `JSON_OBJECT` does the right thing (under "Examples"), so you could conceivably use that to work around the issue (if it's accurate).

Comment: A cheesy way of "fixing" the issue is to replace `[.`, `[-.`, `,.` and `,-.` in the resulting text with their correct equivalents. The problem with this is that it might mutilate strings that legitimately contain these sequences, but that should be relatively uncommon. Especially if you can make it `[.0` et al., since it seems to fail only if the first decimal is 0.

Comment: Finally (with some apologies for the comment train) if you aren't married to JSON, but are using this as a way to transport data between Oracle and SQL Server, both also have support for producing and processing XML, and support for that is more mature than JSON. Of course, producing JSON in Oracle by string concatenation (bypassing the built-in functions) is also possible for simple use cases, if inelegant.

Comment: @JeroenMostert `JSON_OBJECT` has the same non-compliant behavior. `SELECT json_object(''x'' VALUE -0.05) "json_output" FROM DUAL` -> `{"x":-.05}` . The documentation's example is 0.5, not 0.05. Oracle's behavior is inconsistent between the two.

Comment: Unfortunate. That leaves you with the option of outputting string values rather than numbers as the most promising option. I assume Oracle has no problem with those... There is no way to modify SQL Server's behavior for parsing JSON, so you're looking at modifying the input somehow, in any case. Your pick whether to do it at the Oracle end or the SQL Server end (or both).